# How to create Screw shape using Eyeshot's functions

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, cad, eyeshot

I need to create screw shape using Eyeshot's libraries in .NET application.

In SolidWorks this is easily accomplished with creating the shape/profile that needs to be swept/stretched, and helix curve which is used as a rail or direction.

In SolidWorks positioning helix start point to some point in profile's diameter and using "Sweep" command results that point to be driven/rotated around the helix and the wanted shape is created.

> [SolidWorks example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleOI.png)

In Eyeshot I create my profile as a `LinearPath` entity and use

```
SweepAsSolid(ICurve rail, double tol, sweepMethodType sweepMethod = sweepMethodType.RotationMinimizingFrames)
```

function but the result is different. It seems that SweepAsSolid function position helix start point in the center of the profile and different shape is created.

- Using helix as a rail:
  [Eyeshot example with helix as a rail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7vdP.png)
- Using straight line as a rail:
  [Eyeshot example with straight line as a rail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5cvz.png)

Is there a way to get wanted shape with Eyeshot's libraries using the same procedure as in SolidWorks?

Answer (score 1):

I think the method ExtrudeWithTwist() is what you are looking for:

```
            Point3D moveText = new Point3D(0,3,0);

            // new example
            Line l1 = new Line(-3, 0, 3, 0);
            Line l2 = new Line(3, 0, 3, 2);
            Line l3 = new Line(3, 2, -3, 2);
            Line l4 = new Line(-3, 2, -3, 0);

            CompositeCurve cc1 = new CompositeCurve(l1, l2, l3, l4);
 
            Surface[] loft1 = Surface.ExtrudeWithTwist(cc1, new Vector3D(0, 0, -10), new Point3D(0, 1, 0), Math.PI, 0.1);
            foreach (Surface s in loft1)
            {
                s.Translate(10, 0, 0);
            }
            model.Entities.AddRange(loft1, 0, Color.Orange);
```

[image: the result]